# Is the following use of the adverb 'immediately' accurate?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

> You will need to refresh your login details when you first access the new site and the process for doing so will be self evident immediately you try to login.

Is this an accurate use of the word immediately? Should it have a 'when' or an 'after' after it?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at [this definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/immediately) - scroll down to the example at 'conjunction'.

Comment: Yes; but to make it more readable, put a  comma after *site* and  a hyphen between *self* and *evident*. Then it will sound better if the word order is changed: *... and the process for doing so will be immediately self-evident when you try to log in.* (I've only seen *login* used as a noun. This may be changing however.)

Comment: Note that the definition @Lawrence provided has the remark *British* and this kind of use might not be understood elsewhere.

Comment: @Lawrence even though the dictionary calls that usage a "Britishism", I, a British person, think it's wrong, FWIW.  So even if it is a Britishism then I think it should be ignored, and that the given text needs to be amended.

Comment: @Helmar: Hmm. [This NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=knew+immediately+it&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cknew%20immediately%20it%3B%2Cc0) for ***knew immediately it*** suggests that particular sequence is twice as likely in AmE as BrE, and my guess is most instances would represent the specific context we're talking about here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I **knew immediately, it** was a good idea would fit that pattern, wouldn't it?

Comment: @DavidHandelman If I use it as a verb I write it as two words *log in*. But the noun remains *login*.

Comment: @Helmar: Sure. But as I said, my guess is *most* instances will reflect the construction here, even if some don't. In any case, is it really credible that contexts giving rise to alternative constructions are for some reason more likely to occur in AmE than in BrE? I doubt that, so my point would probably still be valid even if most instances in that NGram *weren't* for the exact construction we're dealing with here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Regarding your earlier comment: I clicked on the the Ngram's link to see some examples (rightmost link - presumably representing the full period). I don't think any of those on the first page are of this construction - they look like *I knew immediately it was [noun phrase]*, with *immediately* used as an adverb to *knew*.

Comment: @MaxWilliams (also with reference to FumbleFingers' second comment) I don't particularly like the use of *immediately* as a conjunction, regardless of geography. What matters here, though, is that the construct is sufficiently well-established in usage to be recognised as a legitimate construct.

Comment: @Lawrence I'm not convinced that it **is** well established though.  You just said yourself that the examples you saw weren't actually using it as a conjunction, but rather as an adverb.

Comment: @Lawrence I stand corrected, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

No, *immediately* is not used as an adverb in that context, but yes, your quote is "an accurate use of the word immediately". ODO considers *immediately* to be a *conjunction* when used that way:

> **immediately** *conjunction*
> (British)
> As soon as.
> *‘let me know immediately she arrives’*

There was some discussion in the comments to your question about whether this is actually a British construct. The Ngram corpus, filtered separately for [British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=immediately%20they%20arrive%2Cimmediately%20when%20they%20arrive&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimmediately%20they%20arrive%3B%2Cc0) and [American](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=immediately%20they%20arrive%2Cimmediately%20when%20they%20arrive&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimmediately%20they%20arrive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimmediately%20when%20they%20arrive%3B%2Cc0) usage, seems to support the dictionary's assertion, but the construct appears in American usage as well. The searches were performed using the sentence fragments "immediately they arrive" and "immediately when they arrive", the former using *immediately* as a conjunction and the latter using it as an adverb:

[image]
[image]

As a matter of personal taste, I don't like this usage of *immediately*. Replacing it with *as soon as* sounds much nicer to me:

- ... the process for doing so will be self evident *as soon as* you try to login.

Comment: I think this is quite right. Although the *full* OED has only one entry for ***immediately***, headed as ***adv***, their final definition 3b is: *as **conj.** (ellipt. for **immediately that**). The moment that; as soon as.*

Answer (score 0):

You will need to refresh your login details when you first access the new site and the process for doing so will be self evident immediately AFTER you try to login.